# Efficient Reallocation of CUDA memory

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpu, heap-memory

Let's say we keep a 100MB global memory buffer for a cuda operation alive. In the next calculation, the results are larger than 100MB, e.g. 120MB, and we know this number before the real results come out. In this case, we need to reallocate this memory fragment to 120MB. The question is, can we just create a new memory of 20MB and concatenate it to the existing 100MB? So that we can avoid the latency of a FREE of a 100 MB fragment and a MALLOC of a 120 MB fragment.

Comment: You could use `cudaMallocAsync`

Comment: @AbatorAbetor Does this API allocates a contiguous memory w.r.t. the previous memory space?

Comment: no, `cudaMallocAsync` doesn't guarantee that two separate allocation requests will be contiguous, nor does it allow you to request that/force that.

Comment: cudaMallocAsync can reduce the latency of FREE and MALLOC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, can we just create a new memory of 20MB and concatenate it to the existing 100MB?

You can't do this with `cudaMalloc`, `cudaMallocManaged`, or `cudaHostAlloc`.  The reason is that there is no way to ensure that the 20MB allocation/pointer will be contiguous to the previous 100MB allocation, and there is no way to request that or force that using those allocation APIs.
And any "buffer-like" usage of the 120MB space is going to expect that the space is contiguous.

As indicated in the comments (below), [the Virtual Memory Management API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-memory-management) is intended to allow for roughly this.

You could of course write your own allocation system, that starts by allocating a large contiguous space, and then gives you the controls to do what you are suggesting - basically ask for the "next" 20MB.  How to do that is beyond the scope of my answer.

I believe another possible suggestion is:

1. Allocate a buffer that is larger than initially needed, sized to cover the most likely cases/sizes that may ultimately be needed.
2. Have a reallocation system (an if-test) that checks the new size needed against the current buffer size, and reallocates it larger if needed.  ("reallocates" means freeing the existing buffer and allocating a new one)

Yes, I understand the usual objection: "but I don't know what the largest size may be".  That is understood.  The above mechanism accounts for that.  But if you really cannot provide any sort of "upper bound" based on your knowledge of what you are doing, then there is no guarantee that you will have enough GPU memory anyway, when you discover that more space is needed.

The basic steps to follow using the [virtual memory management method](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introducing-low-level-gpu-virtual-memory-management/) are as follows:

1. allocate, using `cuMemCreate`, a physical device allocation, say of 100MB
2. create a large virtual address allocation, large enough to cover whatever possible eventual size might be needed, using `cuMemAddressReserve`
3. map the 100MB allocation into the beginning of the reserved virtual address range, using `cuMemMap` and make it accessible using `cuMemSetAccess`
4. (presumably, later) allocate a 20MB physical allocation using `cuMemCreate`
5. map this 20MB physical allocation into the next "open" space in the virtual address allocation, immediately after the 100MB allocation, using `cuMemMap` and make it accessible using `cuMemSetAccess`

Here is an example following that sequence:

```
$ cat t2075.cu
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

__global__ void fill(unsigned char *d, size_t size, unsigned char val){
    for (size_t i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < size; i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x)
      d[i] = val;
}

size_t ROUND_UP(size_t size, size_t granularity){
    size_t mult = ceil(size/(double)granularity);
    return mult*granularity;
}

CUmemGenericAllocationHandle allocatePhysicalMemory(int device, size_t size) {
    CUmemAllocationProp prop = {};
    prop.type = CU_MEM_ALLOCATION_TYPE_PINNED;
    prop.location.type = CU_MEM_LOCATION_TYPE_DEVICE;
    prop.location.id = device;
    size_t granularity;
    CUresult result = cuMemGetAllocationGranularity(&granularity, &prop, CU_MEM_ALLOC_GRANULARITY_MINIMUM);
    assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    // Ensure size matches granularity requirements for the allocation
    size_t padded_size = ROUND_UP(size, granularity);
    // Allocate physical memory
    CUmemGenericAllocationHandle allocHandle;
    result = cuMemCreate(&allocHandle, padded_size, &prop, 0);
    assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);

    return allocHandle;
}

void setAccessOnDevice(int device, CUdeviceptr ptr, size_t size) {
    CUmemAccessDesc accessDesc = {};
    accessDesc.location.type = CU_MEM_LOCATION_TYPE_DEVICE;
    accessDesc.location.id = device;
    accessDesc.flags = CU_MEM_ACCESS_FLAGS_PROT_READWRITE;

    // Make the address accessible
    CUresult result = cuMemSetAccess(ptr, size, &accessDesc, 1);
    assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
}

const size_t first_chunk_size = 100ULL*1048576;
const size_t second_chunk_size = 20ULL*1048576;
const size_t total_size = first_chunk_size+second_chunk_size;
int main(){

// test for support
  CUdevice device;
  int device_id = 0;
  cuInit(0);
  CUresult result = cuDeviceGet(&device, device_id);
  assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
  int deviceSupportsVmm = 0;
  result = cuDeviceGetAttribute(&deviceSupportsVmm, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_SUPPORTED, device);
  assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
  if (deviceSupportsVmm == 0) {
    std::cout << "Not supported!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  // `device` supports Virtual Memory Management
  // allocate first chunk
  CUmemGenericAllocationHandle h1 =  allocatePhysicalMemory(device_id, first_chunk_size);
  CUdeviceptr ptr;
// `ptr` holds the returned start of virtual address range reserved.
  result = cuMemAddressReserve(&ptr, total_size, 0, 0, 0); // alignment = 0 for default alignment
  assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
  // `ptr`: address in the address range previously reserved by cuMemAddressReserve.
// `allocHandle`: CUmemGenericAllocationHandle obtained by a previous call to cuMemCreate.
  result = cuMemMap(ptr, first_chunk_size, 0, h1, 0);
  assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
  // enable access to first chunk
  setAccessOnDevice(device_id, ptr, first_chunk_size);
  unsigned char *d = (unsigned char *)ptr;
  // test access to first chunk
  fill<<<80, 1024>>>(d, first_chunk_size, 0);
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  assert(err == cudaSuccess);
  err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  //allocate second chunk
  CUmemGenericAllocationHandle h2 =  allocatePhysicalMemory(device_id, second_chunk_size);
  // map second chunk
  result = cuMemMap(ptr+first_chunk_size, second_chunk_size, 0, h2, 0);
  assert(result == CUDA_SUCCESS);
  // enable access to second chunk
  setAccessOnDevice(device_id, ptr+first_chunk_size, second_chunk_size);
  // test access to both chunks
  fill<<<80, 1024>>>(d, total_size, 0);
  err = cudaGetLastError();
  assert(err == cudaSuccess);
  err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  assert(err == cudaSuccess);
}
$ nvcc -o t2075 t2075.cu -lcuda
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2075
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

CUDA 11.4, V100, CentOS 7

A few observations:

- I have tested this on both cc3.5 and cc7.0 devices.
- On cc7.0 device the minimum allocation granularity is 2MB.  For reasons of sanity, if I were using this process, I would be sure to only request and map multiples of the minimum allocation granularity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "your own allocation system" is exactly what I expect. But you mean that even if I have my own allocation pipeline, I still need to start by allocating a large contiguous space, e.g. 500MB, then move the pointer to the desired "20MB" that is located adjacent to the previous 100MB space.  This seems to be redundant and less meaningful since I can directly use this 500MB as the buffer for my operation like your first suggestion. So, can we say that the custom allocation system makes no sense in this application?

Comment: Yes, basically.  A custom allocator would normally be used for more than a single allocation. If there is only a single allocation, then you don't need a custom allocator and instead just implement the steps 1 and 2 that I indicated.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Isn't this actually possible through the [Virtual Memory Management API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-memory-management)?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example for that.

Comment: The blog post also links to full implementation of a device vector using virtual memory. https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/posts/cuda-vmm/cuvector.cpp

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Robert Crovella's answer I would like to show that memory pool allocations via `cudaMallocAsync` can reduce the latency.

The following code grows an allocation 50 times by 20 MB by simply freeing the buffer and allocating a larger one. The next buffer size is computed via kernel to emulate computation of result size of an operation.

```
// compiled with nvcc -O3 main.cu -o main
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#if 0

    cudaError_t allocate(void** ptr, size_t size, cudaStream_t stream){
        return cudaMallocAsync(ptr, size, stream);
    }

    cudaError_t deallocate(void* ptr, cudaStream_t stream){
        return cudaFreeAsync(ptr, stream);
    }

#else

    cudaError_t allocate(void** ptr, size_t size, cudaStream_t){
        return cudaMalloc(ptr, size);
    }

    cudaError_t deallocate(void* ptr, cudaStream_t){
        return cudaFree(ptr);
    }

#endif

__global__
void computeNextSize(size_t* size, size_t growBy){
    *size = *size + growBy;
}

int main(){
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaStream_t stream = cudaStreamPerThread;
    const size_t mb20 = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

    size_t* h_size = nullptr;
    size_t* d_size = nullptr;

    cudaMalloc(&d_size, sizeof(size_t));
    cudaMallocHost(&h_size, sizeof(size_t));
    *h_size = mb20;
    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_size, h_size, sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);

    cudaMemPool_t memPool;
    cudaDeviceGetMemPool(&memPool, 0);
    size_t setVal = UINT64_MAX;
    cudaMemPoolSetAttribute(memPool, cudaMemPoolAttrReleaseThreshold, &setVal);

    void* ptr = nullptr;
    size_t size = mb20;
    allocate(&ptr, size, stream);
    //std::cout << "size: " << size << ", ptr = " << ptr << "\n";
    cudaMemsetAsync(ptr, 0, size); //work with ptr
    computeNextSize<<<1,1,0,stream>>>(d_size, mb20);
    cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream); //wait for computation and transfer of next size


    auto a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        deallocate(ptr, stream);
        size = *h_size;
        allocate(&ptr, size, stream);
        //std::cout << "size: " << size << ", ptr = " << ptr << "\n";
        cudaMemsetAsync(ptr, 0, size); //work with ptr
        computeNextSize<<<1,1,0,stream>>>(d_size, mb20);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(h_size, d_size, sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream); //wait for computation and transfer of next size
    }
    deallocate(ptr, stream);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

    auto b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const std::chrono::duration<double> delta = b - a;
    std::cerr << delta.count() << "s\n";
}
```

With `cudaMalloc` the code takes around 0.596s,
with `cudaMallocAsync` the duration is around 0.092s

Comment: How does it work? Does **cudaFreeAsync** not really release the memory but put it into a buffer? and the **cudaMallocAsync** just reuse the buffer and put it together with a new memory fragment?

Comment: @Worldbuffer The async API does have some pooling/caching functionality to avoid reallocating the same size over and over again. But in this case I would think that the speedup just comes from the asynchronicity. I.e. each synchronization causes an overhead and `cudaMalloc` etc. implicitly cause synchronization. By doing it in a loop the effect gets quite big especially as there is not that many other expensive operations in between.

Comment: @Worldbuffer [This blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-cuda-stream-ordered-memory-allocator-part-1/) goes into detail about the async allocations and their pool functionality.